# VS Code: How to exclude folders from npm task auto-detection?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code shows configured and auto-detected tasks in its `Run Tasks` menu. I would like to exclude the `bin` folder and all its subfolders from the npm task auto-detection. The [npm.exclude](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_npm-script-running) setting appears to be designed for that purpose, but I haven't found how to use it.

I tried the following variations, with no success:

```
"npm.exclude": "**/bin"
"npm.exclude": "**/bin/"
"npm.exclude": "./bin"
"npm.exclude": "./bin/"
"npm.exclude": "**/bin/*.*"
"npm.exclude": "./bin/*.*"
"npm.exclude": ["**/bin"]
"npm.exclude": ["**/bin/"]
"npm.exclude": ["./bin"]
"npm.exclude": ["./bin/"]
"npm.exclude": ["**/bin/*.*"]
"npm.exclude": ["./bin/*.*"]
```

The syntax used for `files.exclude` and `search.exclude` doesn't appear to be allowed:

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**/.git": true,
     "**/.svn": true,
     "**/.hg": true
 }
```

What is the appropriate syntax for the `npm.exclude` setting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try (in your `settings.json`)

```
"npm.exclude": "**/bin/**"
```

that works for me to exclude scripts in workspaceFolder/bin/package.json

Comment: It seems it's matching the glob against the directory's _absolute_ path.  The following also works for me:


```json
"npm.exclude": [
  "/Users/me/myproj/build",
  "/Users/me/myproj/build/**",
]
```


The first excludes files in build itself, the second files in subdirectories.

Shouldn't it match relative paths rather than/as well as absolute?

VSCode 1.33.1 Mac.

Comment: In which file we have to put this 'npm.exclude' configuration?

Comment: @rineez, In the base of your project create `.vscode/settings.json`, and add `{"npm.exclude": ["**/.venv/**"]}` there.

Comment: This work for me `"npm.exclude": ["**/bin/** ", "**/bin"]` and use `"npm.scriptExplorerExclude": ["start"]` to exclude a specific script (start in here) in all scripts in settings.json

Answer (score 11):

"**npm.exclude**" requires a "*string* and uses *glob*. So, my settings for npm.exclude, with multiple rules:

```
"npm.exclude": "**/@(vendor|node_modules|bower_components|dist|static)/**"
```

Comment: This works for me, however, does it handle hidden folders? My project has a folder `.cache` with a `package.json` in its root. This gets displayed in my NPM scripts even though I have `.cache` included in the string e.g. `**/@(vendor|node_modules|bower_components|dist|static|.cache)/**`.

Answer (score 0):

You were only missing few things:

- `"npm.exclude": ["**/bin/**"]` has to be in `settings.json` in your project's `.vscode/settings.json` file.
- In regards to the other answers i.e: `"**/@(vendor|node_modules|bower_components|dist|static)/**"`. It would be better to use an array instead for more readability, i.e:

```
  "npm.exclude": [
    "**/dist/**", // note how "dist" here is added even though it's at the root of the folder for example, same goes for node_modules. For some reason, setting it to something like this "node_modules/**" won't work.
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/bin/**"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this did not work:

```
  "npm.exclude": ["**/dist/**"]
```

But this did

```
  "npm.exclude": ["**/dist"]
```